Safari is limiting the expiration of authentication cookie to 7 days
Safari is limiting my auth cookie to 7 days. This is weird since:

Should be a first party cookie (Cookie has Domain=.mydomain.com, my SPA hosted on app.mydomain.com and the API that serves the cookie on api.mydomain.com)

It's not ITP related as far as I can see as I enabled "ITP debug mode" and didn't see my domain on the list of domains with cross-site tracking restrictions.


This is the value of the response header
Set-Cookie: rc_auth_token=<Redacted>; HttpOnly; Path=/; Max-Age=7775999; Domain=.mydomain.com; SameSite=Lax; Secure

However when going to Storage > Cookies, I can see that Safari sets the expiration to just 7 days from now.
Any thoughts on what can be causing Safari to limit the expiration of my cookie to 7 days?
